# AR Core virtual scene not showing in Emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, arcore

I've set up an Android Emulator with Android Studio (3.6.3) and installed the most recent ARCore.apk (1.16.0). The Emulator in SDKTools is V30.0.5. I'm using a Pixel 3a API27 Android 8.1 Emulator with Unity 2018.4.20f1.

My first scene, which does not use ARCore is working fine but once I try to access an AR scene it only shows a black room with blue dots in the sky and some grey flooring. The description, how to move the camera etc. shows up, but not the virtual scene with the table, which I need for testing.
[Screenshot of the loaded Scene in the Emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E999X.png)

Android Studio shows this error code:

```
Emulator: C:\buildbot\src\android\emu-master-dev\external\qemu\android\android-emugl\host\libs\Translator\GLES_V2\GLESv2Imp.cpp:glFramebufferTexture2D:1544 error 0x500

Emulator: C:\buildbot\src\android\emu-master-dev\external\qemu\android\android-emugl\host\libs\Translator\GLES_V2\GLESv2Imp.cpp:glFramebufferTexture2D:1544 error 0x500
```

The Camera Back is set to virtual scene.
I've tried making a different emulator and cold booting but no improvements.

I've already tried setting Emulated Performance ==> Graphics ==> "Software - GLES 2.0" as per another thread here but that only reduced the amount of errors to the upper two.

Does anyone have any ideas?